# Recursive observer does not see all directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-watchdog

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler

class MyHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        print(f'event type: {event.event_type}  path : {event.src_path} isdir : {event.is_directory}')


event_handler = MyHandler(patterns=['*'],ignore_patterns=['*.txt'])
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, path='watch/', recursive=True)
observer.start()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
observer.join()
```

I have this simple watcher app where the objective is to log any files or directories that are not `.txt`. I'm not sure if this is a bug, or something I'm not understanding.

When I have `observer.schedule` set with `recursive=True` and then copy multiple directories (with files within) into the watched folder, only one directory and it's sub files will be logged, the other ones do not trigger the event handler. Moving each directory one after another will log each directory respectively, the problem is only when moving in multiples. I'm using windows 10, and I'm moving 3 directories, each with about 10 files each.

If I change `recursive=False` all directories and sub folders are logged correctly. I don't really know what the difference is since sub files are being logged regardless of it's recursive or not, other than the above behavior.

EDIT:

I have raised an issue on [watchdogs git](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog/issues/596) with further details

Comment: This comment from the source might give you a hint: https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog/blob/master/src/watchdog/observers/read_directory_changes.py#L90 It seems when recursive is true a hack is used to try to wait for I/O to complete, but I/O not completed within the 1 second time window will be missed. Could be related?

Comment: I don't see how that could be the issue, all the files are small and the IOs are quick